# Unblocking application at runtime

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am unblocking the executable at runtime (meaning I remove the `:Zone.Identifier` binary tag from the application.

My question is whether I have to reboot the application in order for it to run as if it was unblocked to begin with.

This is the application: https://mobasuite.com/

```
    // Self-Unblocking
static const WCHAR stream_name[] = L":Zone.Identifier";
WCHAR fileName[MAX_PATH + _countof(stream_name)] = { 0 };
DWORD length = MAX_PATH;
QueryFullProcessImageName(GetCurrentProcess(), 0, fileName, &length);
wcscpy_s(fileName + length, _countof(fileName) - length, stream_name);
DeleteFile(fileName);
```

It would be very helpful if you could help me with this, since it would ease the installation process of the app.

Comment: Yes, the process will need to be restarted. Removing the zone AFS on the running executable doesn't look to be very good practice. Why did you think that would be the solution to your problem, whatever it is

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It was such a long time ago I wrote the base for this app that I've forgotten why unblocking the app is required in the first place.
I do have an 'unblock' class in it, the full code is [here](https://github.com/MOBASuite/MOBAUpdater/blob/master/source.cpp)

Since you reminded me now, I don't think this is even necessary.